# Read SMS Message from Inbox in conversation in android

Tags: android, sms, message

i am developing an messaging app, i want to get all my messages into a conversation list
i am trying the code below but it is for just read all the messages from inbox, not conversation

```
            Uri inboxURI = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");

            String[] reqCols = new String[] { "_id", "address", "body" };

            ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();

            Cursor c = cr.query(inboxURI, reqCols, null, null, null);

            adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(context, R.layout.message_box_view, c,
                    new String[] { "address", "body" }, new int[] {
                    R.id.tv_message_box_number, R.id.tv_message_box_text }, 1);

            lv_messagesBox.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using this code to fetch inbox -

```
Uri mSmsinboxQueryUri = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
Cursor cursor1 = getContentResolver().query(mSmsinboxQueryUri,new String[] { "_id", "thread_id", "address", "person", "date","body", "type" }, null, null, null);
startManagingCursor(cursor1);
String[] columns = new String[] { "address", "person", "date", "body","type" };
if (cursor1.getCount() > 0) {
   String count = Integer.toString(cursor1.getCount());
   while (cursor1.moveToNext()){
       String address = cursor1.getString(cursor1.getColumnIndex(columns[0]));
       String name = cursor1.getString(cursor1.getColumnIndex(columns[1]));
       String date = cursor1.getString(cursor1.getColumnIndex(columns[2]));
       String msg = cursor1.getString(cursor1.getColumnIndex(columns[3]));
       String type = cursor1.getString(cursor1.getColumnIndex(columns[4]));
    }
}
```

Fetch sent sms by this URI -

```
Uri mSmsinboxQueryUri = Uri.parse("content://sms/sent");
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: yes i already have fetch the inbox and sent messages, but it is separately like inbox and out box, but i want a conversation view

Answer (score 1):

i solved my problem by this

```
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://sms/");
    String[] reqCols = new String[] { "_id", "body", "address", "read", "date", "type", "thread_id" };

    ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
    Cursor cursor = cr.query(uri, reqCols, "thread_id = '" + threadId + "'" , null, "date ASC");
```